# In QT, chaining models does not work as expected

Tags: qt, proxy, model, view, chaining

Alright, I have a really basic `QStandardItemModel`, filled with some numbers. I managed to display it in a `QTableView`, it's ok. I created a new model ( subclass either of `QAbstractItemModel` or `QAbstractProxyModel` ), which is some kind of a layer of an existing model - it is needed to set the sourcemodel, and this new layer should do some transformations on the real one.

My problem is, that in the top layer, say "layer model" the `data( const QModelIndex & index, int role )` member function never called, however i would like to alter the displaying methods by the role parameter.

Here is a sample code, which demonstrates, that the original model's `data(index,role)` is always called, whilst the layer model's `data(index,role)` never. Why? How can the QTableView object "skip" the top layer's `data(index,role)` ?

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QStandardItemModel>

class MyModel : public QStandardItemModel
{
public:
    MyModel(const int r, const int c, QObject* parent = 0) : QStandardItemModel(r,c,parent) {}
    QVariant data ( const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole ) const {
        qDebug() << "mymodel data";
        return this->itemFromIndex(index)->data(role);
    }
};

class MyProxyModel : public QAbstractProxyModel
{
public:

    MyProxyModel(QObject* parent = 0) : QAbstractProxyModel(parent) {}
    QModelIndex index ( int row, int column, const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex() ) const {
        return this->sourceModel()->index(row,column,parent);
    }
    QModelIndex parent ( const QModelIndex & index ) const {
        return this->sourceModel()->parent(index);
    }
    QModelIndex mapFromSource ( const QModelIndex & sourceIndex ) const
    {
        return sourceIndex;
    }
    QModelIndex mapToSource ( const QModelIndex & proxyIndex ) const
    {
        return proxyIndex;
    }
    QVariant data ( const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole ) const {
        qDebug() << "myproxymodel data";
        return this->sourceModel()->data(index,role);
    }

    int rowCount ( const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex() ) const {
        return this->sourceModel()->rowCount(parent);
    }
    int columnCount ( const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex() ) const {
        return this->sourceModel()->columnCount(parent);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);
    MyModel model(8, 2);
    MyProxyModel mymodel;
    mymodel.setSourceModel(&model);

    QTableView tableView;
    tableView.setModel(&mymodel);

    tableView.horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
    for (int row = 0; row < 8; ++row) {
        for (int column = 0; column < 2; ++column) {
            QModelIndex index = model.index(row, column, QModelIndex());
            model.setData(index, QVariant((row+1) * (column+1)));
        }

    }
    tableView.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because QTableView uses the model index to retrieve the data, probably something like this.

```
QModelIndex index = model->index(row, column, parentIndex); 
index.data(Qt::DisplayRole);
```

And you are returning the model index of the source model instead of an index to your proxy model:

```
QModelIndex index ( int row, int column, const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex() ) const {
    return this->sourceModel()->index(row,column,parent);
}
```

Try to convert the model index into an index to your proxy model

```
QModelIndex index ( int row, int column, const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex() ) const {
    return this->createIndex(row,column,row);
}
```

Don't forget to rewrite the map to source and map from source functions.

---

**Solution**

```
class MyTableProxyModel : public QAbstractProxyModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyTableProxyModel (QObject* parent = 0) 
        : QAbstractProxyModel(parent) {
    }

    QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex& parent=QModelIndex()) const {
        return createIndex(row,column,row);
    }

    QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &index) const {
        //Works only for non-tree models
        return QModelIndex();
    }

    QModelIndex mapFromSource(const QModelIndex &source) const {
        return index(source.row(), source.column(), source.parent());
    }

    QModelIndex mapToSource(const QModelIndex &proxy) const {
        return (sourceModel()&&proxy.isValid())
            ? sourceModel()->index(proxy.row(), proxy.column(), proxy.parent()) 
            : QModelIndex();
    }

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role=Qt::DisplayRole) const {
        qDebug() << "myproxymodel data";
        return mapToSource(index).data(role);
    }

    int rowCount ( const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex() ) const {
        return sourceModel() ? sourceModel()->rowCount(parent) : 0;
    }

    int columnCount ( const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex() ) const {
        return sourceModel() ? sourceModel()->columnCount(parent) : 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: Ok, I see. I have then 2 questions:
- How can i achieve my goal without creating proxy indexes? I'd like to avoid creating indexes in the proxy model, because there won't be any filtering/sorting, etc, and that would be a complete duplication of the original models's indexes.
- I don't see how the `QSortFilterProxyModel` can help me out. I have to code the `data(..)` function, and because of the above, I need also code the `index(...)` too. What `QSortFilterProxyModel` does that `QAbstractProxyModel` doesn't in my point of view?

Comment: You need to create new indexes that are pointing to the proxy model. QSortFilterProxyMode creates the proxy indexes for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, the mapToSource and mapFromSource were the devil's eyes for me! That works like a charm!

Comment: Not quite right: your implementation of mapToSource() is passing a proxy.parent() to the source model, which is expecting a source index for the parent. Of course, this works given that your parent function is just returning QModelIndex() and you aren't trying to support tree models.

Comment: [puetzk](http://stackoverflow.com/users/14312/puetzk) is correct. Not only is `mapToSource()` incorrect, but `mapFromSource` is too! You pass the source index `source.parent()` into the proxy's `index()` function. A properly done proxy must reject such indices. Look at `QIdentityProxyModel` to see the necessary precondition checks.

Comment: In a nutshell: model indices contain a reference to the model they work on. A valid index works on one model only: the one returned by the `model()` method.