# Create a proxy of QAbstractModelItem

Tags: c++, qt, proxy, qabstractitemmodel

I'm writing a Qt application to allow the visualization of very heavy data sets.

So, I have a `SourceDataModel` class, inheriting from `QAbstractItemModel` that seems to work properly (currently, I only display it in QTableView/QTreeView but later on, I'll create some custom views).

Now, I would like to be able to filter this data, that is

1. being able to have different data
   resolution (i.e. only exposing 1
   data item out of 2)
2. being able to
   apply some filters on the data (i.e.
   displaying unix timestamps as
   dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss)

So I started to create a `ProxySourceDataModel` class, which inherits from my `SourceDataModel` and stores one instance, and basically delegates everything to the instance. From this `ProxySourceDataModel`, I noticed that no data was displayed when I used it in a `QTableView`. After some investigation, it seems that it was because i had to forward the signals and slots from the underlying `SourceDataModel`. No problem, i did it.

But still 2 problems remain, and I can't figure out how to handle them:

1. I am not able to select the data in the views. If I use the `SourceDataModel` directly, no problem. But using the `ProxySourceDataModel` i can't select anything.
2. The data is not filtered at all! I overloaded data() in `ProxySourceDataModel`, and forward all the other calls to the underlying `SourceDataModel`. But still, only `SourceDataModel::data()` is called.

Here is some code to illustrate what I'm doing:

```
class SourceDataModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
  //...
};

class ProxySourceDataModel : public SourceDataModel
{
public:
  ProxySourceDataModel(SourceDataModel& model)
    : model_(model)
  {
    // For all QAbstractItemModel's signals emitted by the underlying model,
    // I propagate them like this
    QObject::connect( &model_, SIGNAL(        the_signal()),
                      this,    SLOT  (forward_the_signal())) ;
  }

slots:
  void forward_the_signal()
  {
    emit the_signal();
  }

public:
  // For all QAbstractItemModel's virtual function, I do something like this
  virtual void the_function()
  {
    model_.the_function();
  }

  // This is where I was hoping to do the filtering
  virtual QVariant data( const QModelIndex& index,int role=Qt::DisplayRole )
  {
    return filter( model_.data(index,role) );
  }

private:
  SourceDataModel& model_;
};

SourceDataModel sourceDataModel;
QTableView      view;
view.setModel( new ProxySourceDataModel(sourceDataModel) );
```

Any help or advice greatly appreciated, thanks for reading!

**-------------------- EDIT ------------------------**

**I found it!**

The problem was that the view do not use `QAbstractItemModel::data()` from its model, but rather calls `QModelIndex::data()` on its items, which in turn calls the `QAbstractItemModel::data()` of the item's underlying model.
And since my proxy returned model indexes from the underlying model, that is why the `SourceDataModel::data()` was always called instead of `ProxySourceDataModel()`!

I just reimplemented `ProxySourceDataModel::index()` to return local indexes, and it works like a charm.
Visit [In QT, chaining models does not work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387912/in-qt-chaining-models-does-not-work-as-expected) for more informations.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [In QT, chaining models does not work as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387912/in-qt-chaining-models-does-not-work-as-expected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the view do not use `QAbstractItemModel::data()` from its model, but rather calls `QModelIndex::data()` on its items, which in turn calls the `QAbstractItemModel::data()` of the item's underlying model.
And since my proxy returned model indexes from the underlying model, that is why the `SourceDataModel::data()` was always called instead of `ProxySourceDataModel()`!

I just reimplemented `ProxySourceDataModel::index()` to return local indexes, and it works like a charm.
Visit [In QT, chaining models does not work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387912/in-qt-chaining-models-does-not-work-as-expected) for more informations.